# Code Generation form Uml Modeling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have added the class to the class diagram in vs 2010 now i want to generate the code from the class  diagrams. How can i generate the code in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN article [How to: Generate Code from UML Class Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx)

> To generate a separate file for each
>   element
>
> 1. Create a UML model that contains classes. You might want to apply
>      stereotypes to the model elements. For
>      more information, see Default Code
>      Generation Transforms.
> 2. On a class diagram or in UML Model Explorer, select elements from which
>      you want to generate code. You can
>      select one of the following:  A
>      specific set of elements.
>
>    A package or the model, to generate
>      code from its contents.
>       The diagram, to select all the elements on the diagram.
> 3. Right-click a selected element, and then click Generate Code.
>
> The first time that you use Generate
>   Code in a particular model, a dialog
>   box appears. This dialog box lets you
>   edit the code generation parameters of
>   the model.
>
> Click OK unless you know that you want
>   to change these parameters.
>
> To return to this dialog box later,
>   right-click the diagram and then click
>   Configure Default Code Generation
>   Settings. For more information, see
>   Customizing the Generate Code Command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But the problem is can not find the Generate Code options when I write click the the UML Model. I have followed the steps listed in the article give on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx#default

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the [Visual Studio 2010 feature packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff655021.aspx) to enable this functionality. The most recent one is Feature Pack 2, but you also need to have an MSDN Subscription to download it.